# Python Turtle - Turtle se cierra automaticamente

Tags: python, python-turtle

Soy nuevo usando Turtle, y hice una simple prueba con este codigo:

```
from turtle import *

for i in range(4):
    forward(100)
    left(90)
```

Y funciona, al terminar de hacer la figura se cierra, y en los tutoriales que he visto no pasa eso. ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: No hay problema: tu programa simplemente termina, y con eso se cierran sus ventanas.

Comment: añade un `time.sleep()` al después del bucle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso se debe a que te olvidaste de colocar un llamado a la función [done](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/turtle.html#turtle.done). Esta función llama al mainloop de Tkinter internamente. Este loop "traba" el código, va procesando los eventos de Tkinter y hace que el programa no finalice, evitando el cierre de las ventanas. Si usas Idle (el editor de código que viene opcionalmente con la instalación de Python) el código finaliza pero la ventana no se cierra.